# C# Doesn't insert to mySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have some Steam trading bots and i am trying to insert to a database whether a trade was successful or not (true). You can see my code below. I get absolutely no errors and the regular trades, functions and console logging works fine. I check the db for content and nothing is there.

I am new to SQL in C#. Is someone able to tell me whats wrong with my code?

```
public override void OnTradeAccept()
        {
            bool didSomething = false;
            if ((Validate()) || (IsAdmin && mode == ADMINMODE) || ChooseDonate)
            {
                bool success = Trade.AcceptTrade();
                if (success) //makes sure trades were successfull
                {   
                    //I removed con details
                    string constr = "server=;database=;userid=;password=;";
                    MySqlConnection con = null;
                    try
                    {
                        con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
                        con.Open(); //open the connection

                        string insertTrue = "INSERT INTO trade_success(state) VALUES ('true')";
                        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertTrue, con);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                    catch (MySqlException err) //We will capture and display any MySql errors that will occur
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.ToString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (con != null)
                        {
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    Log.Success("Trade was successful!");
                    //sendChatMessage(tradeSuccessMessage1);
                    sendChatMessage(tradeSuccessMessage2);
                    Bot.SteamFriends.SetPersonaState(EPersonaState.LookingToTrade);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Warn("Trade might have failed.");
                    Bot.SteamFriends.SetPersonaState(EPersonaState.LookingToTrade);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try this `insertTrue` in your database manager? Is it works there?

Comment: You're catching only a certain type of exception, meaning the others go unnoticed, so there might be a problem you don't see. You're also logging success outside of thisso your log might be wrong too. Have you tried running the query against MySQL directly, without passing through C# ?

Comment: i ran this query "INSERT INTO trade_success(state) VALUES ('true')" directly into my DB and it does work.

Comment: Any idea as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't `commit`ing your transaction after you run the query.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but how do i go about doing that?